# Veracrypt decrypt multiple drives at boot

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, encryption, truecrypt

I want to encrypt my C:\ and D:\ drive using veracrypt. And have them both decrypted at boot.

C:\ hosts my OS (win8.1) and D:\ holds most of my installed applications since C:\ only has 90GB of usable space.

Because of their relation I cannot decrypt them separately because then most applications would fail to autostart when Veracrypt has decrypted C:\ at boot but not D:\

I've noticed in [Is it possible to decrypt multiple truecrypt drives at FDE boot?](https://superuser.com/questions/584342/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-multiple-truecrypt-drives-at-fde-boot) that my setup *is* possible when I'm using identical drives. However that doesn't suit me since I'll be using an SSD and HDD.

I also consider decrypting D:\ automatically using a startup-script too late. As I suspect those to run **after** the initialisation of services (which could be hosted on D:\ ).

It's very well possible there is no solution other than to purchase a larger SSD, move applications that auto-start to it, and disable auto-start for applications that I still need hosted on D:\ like Steam.
But I'm hoping someone here knows a way to decrypt multiple drives at boot.